# compare array column of one dataframe to subsets of array column of another dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes like below:

```
df1 = (Receipt_no: String , Items_no_set:Array[String])

+-----------+-------------------+
| Receipt_no| Items_no_set      |
+-----------+-------------------+
|        001| [123,124,125]     |
|        002| [501,502,503,504] |
|        003| [123,501,125]     |
+-----------+-------------------+


df2 = (product_no: String , product_items_set:Array[String])

+-----------+-------------------+
| product_no| product_items_set |
+-----------+-------------------+
|        909| [123,124]         |
|        908| [501,502,503]     |
|        907| [123,501,125]     |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

now I want to compare the df1(Items_no_set) to df2(product_items_set) if a match found return the df3(Receipt_no,Items_no_set,product_no).

If match is not found in above case I want to create the subsets of df1(Items_no_set) and then compare if match is found

my expected output:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+
| Receipt_no| Items_no_set      | product_no|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+
|        001| [123,124]         |   909     |
|        002| [501,502,503,504] |   908     |
|        003| [123,501,125]     |   907     |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I am struggling to achieve the above step and my expected output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no matching key between df1 and df2, we have to do crossJoin. Check out this rdd solution:

```
scala> val df1 = Seq(
     |       ("001",Array(123,124,125)),
     |       ("002",Array(501,502,503,504)),
     |       ("003",Array(123,501,125)) ).toDF("receipt_no","items_no_set")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [receipt_no: string, items_no_set: array<int>]

scala> val df2 = Seq(
     |       ("909",Array(123,124)),
     |       ("908",Array(501,502,503)),
     |       ("907",Array(123,501,125)) ).toDF("product_no","product_items_set")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [product_no: string, product_items_set: array<int>]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [receipt_no: string, items_no_set: array<int> ... 2 more fields]

scala> val rdd2= df3.rdd.filter( x => {
     |             val items = x.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]("items_no_set").toArray;
     |             val prds = x.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]("product_items_set").toArray;
     |             val chk = prds.intersect(items).length == prds.length
     |             ( chk == true )
     |             }
     |             ).map( x => Row(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[76] at map at <console>:50

scala> val schema = df1.schema.add(StructField("product_no",StringType))
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(receipt_no,StringType,true), StructField(items_no_set,ArrayType(IntegerType,false),true), StructField(product_no,StringType,true))

scala> spark.createDataFrame(rdd2,schema).show(false)
+----------+--------------------+----------+
|receipt_no|items_no_set        |product_no|
+----------+--------------------+----------+
|001       |[123, 124, 125]     |909       |
|002       |[501, 502, 503, 504]|908       |
|003       |[123, 501, 125]     |907       |
+----------+--------------------+----------+


scala>
```